# Combination on points

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many triangles are determined by nine points no three of which lie on the same straight line?

This is so confusing from its looks .i.e no three of which lie on straight line. How can i solve this question sir?

Comment: Pick any three points from the nine points that are available. What condition might *prevent* these three points from forming a triangle ?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Any selection of three points not on the same line forms a triangle.

Comment: No 3 points lie on a straight line as stated... Perhaps your post is quite redundant?

Comment: @XcoderX the point of this answer is that the condition given in the question can be rephrased as "any three of which form a triangle", and now it's easy to see how many triangles there are.

Comment: Ah okay!  I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You can select one of $9$ points for your first axis, $8$ are left for the second and $7$ for the third.

However, if we're making a triangle it doesn't matter in what order we select them. **Swapping any two points** results in the same triangle, so we need to divide by 2. It also doesn't matter which of the 3 points we start at, so we again divide by 3.

Hence, there are: $$\frac {9\times 8 \times 7}{3\times 2} =84$$

Comment: Keep patience brother, he will.